# How to connect Moga Pro controller to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth

I was wondering how to connect a Moga Pro bluetooth controller to Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I try to set up a new device on the ubuntu computer via bluetooth, it sees my device, but when I select it, it says to enter a numerical code on the controller, not sure how to go about that. Any advice is helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 15.10 I switched the Moga Pro controller to B. Then started Bluetooth settings. It found a “joypad” named “Moga Pro HID”. In mode A it would have found a “computer” named “Moga Pro” which can not be used.

Then install and start jstest-gtk. All analog and digital buttons on the Moga should do something in this program.